# How to set width of Continuously scrolling carousel immediately stopping onmouseover slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I used the carousel slider which gives exactly what i want but the problem is that it takes dynamic width to the slider which i don't want. As per the desktop screen resolution it set the width of div "caroufredsel_wrapper". I just wanted to set the size of this class to 1024px. What i done is as follows:

```
<div style="height:150px;width:1024px;display:inline-block;">
<div id="carousel" style="overflow:hidden; float:right;">
<div>
<img src="img/1.png" alt="fruit1" width="105" height="116" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/2.jpg" alt="fruit2" width="105" height="116" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/3.jpg" alt="fruit3" width="105" height="116" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/4.jpg" alt="fruit4" width="105" height="116" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/5.jpg" alt="fruit5" width="105" height="116" />       
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/6.jpg" alt="fruit6" width="105" height="116" />       
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/7.jpg" alt="fruit7" width="105" height="116" />       
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/8.jpg" alt="fruit8" width="105" height="116" />               
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/9.jpg" alt="fruit9" width="105" height="116" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/10.jpg" alt="fruit10" width="105" height="116" />     
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/11.jpg" alt="fruit11" width="105" height="116" />             
</div>
<div>
<img src="img/12.jpg" alt="fruit12" width="105" height="116" />                 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
#carousel {
margin-top: 20px;


}


#carousel div {

text-align: center;

width: 130px;

height: 130px;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#carousel div img {
border: none;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #333;        
}
#carousel div span {
display: none;
}
#carousel div:hover span {
background-color: #333;
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 22px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
padding: 2px 0;
margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 30px;
left: 50%;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Then below is the script which i used:

```
var $c = $('#carousel'),
$w = $(window);
$c.carouFredSel({
align: false,
items: 10,
scroll: {
items: 1,
duration: 2000,
timeoutDuration: 0,
easing: 'linear',
pauseOnHover: 'immediate'
}
});
$w.bind('resize.example', function() {
var nw = $w.width();
if (nw < 990) {
nw = 990;
}
$c.width(nw * 3);
$c.parent().width(nw);    
}).trigger('resize.example');   
});
```

Can anybody tell me what should i do set this carousel slider width to 1024px. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I believe that the question is not related to the title of the question.

Comment: Actually carousel slider uses its own jquery package i.e. "<script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" and it sets its slider width according to screen resolution and i just wanted to know how to set it permanently to 1024px. That's all the question is.